Existing data directory error in postgres installation
This message is what I've been getting while installing a new Postgres. I want the data to be stored in a new directory and not the existing one.

An existing data directory has been found at C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\16\data set to use port number 5432. This directory and its configuration will be used for this installation

I've tried uninstalling the existing Postgres from the control panel and app and features but it still remain the same.
Please what can I do in this case?


I downloaded postgres using the EDB installer from postgres official page
I'm not updating the version, I uninstalled the postgres i have on my windows (version 16.0) due to some reasons and i want to install a new one.
But i was able to change it after running the command @Laurenz Albe shared


You don't install PostgreSQL to create a new data directory. All you have to do is run initdb. In your case, that would probably mean
"C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\16\bin\initdb" -U postgres -E UTF8 --locale=en_US "D:\wherever\your\database\should\be"

